# automatic mysql repair check analyze optimize for windows

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012

I've been searching for automatic solution to repair and analyze, optimize and check mysql databases all-in-one with a click, with ability to keep reports, and can be scheduled in task scheduler, I've found a lot of solution but all for Linux, and all command line based..

my need is to have small windows solution for this, server is windows server 2012 and using mysql that have several live databases needs automatic maintenance each while

Automatic backup batch for windows is available, but for maintenance and the above mentioned commands, couldn't find anything related to windows

anybody faced this and can help?

thanks in advanced